# Android Studio v4.1 Signing Report for SHA-1 Problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing

I am using the Android Studio Version 4.1. Before updating, Signing report shows SHA-1 and more. But after updating to the latest version(4.1), Signing Report shows only this.

Is this a bug?

[image: This]

Comment: No, It's not a bug. You can see it by clicking on ":app:signingReport" part in this image.

Comment: No, it's not clickable.

Comment: I mean it's clickable but it just reruns

Comment: @I'madeveloper where need to click?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I'm not getting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are clicking on the left side task, it shows the result on the right side of that.

check in the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open android view on android studio, go to terminal, and type

```
gradlew signingReport
```